# why java takes only addition in basic programs

Tags: java, variables, error-handling

Today i have been working over at one basic program of java :

```
class Add
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {   int a=20;
        int b=20;
        int c;
        c=a-b;
        c=a+b;
        System.out.println("c:"+c);

            System.out.println("c:"+c);
    }
}
```

i accidentally typed or used variables twice for addition and subtraction,strangely the result output came without any errors :

Output :

C:40
c:40

why does it happen,why does not java compiler pointed me an error?

the online version of the result can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/Y4PgfM).

thanks in advance

Comment: Java just overwrites the variable.

Comment: what is so strange here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you told Java to do that;

```
int a=20;
int b=20;
final int c=a-b; // <-- make it final, then changing it is a compile error.
final int d=a+b;
System.out.println("c:"+c);
System.out.println("d:"+d);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no error.

```
int a=20;
int b=20;
int c; // c is now uninitialized
c=a-b; // c is set to 0
c=a+b; // c is now set to 40
System.out.println("c:"+c); // print 40
System.out.println("c:"+c); // print 40
```

Comment: variables declared inside a method get no default value, so on int c; c has no value. If it is used before explicit initialization a compilation error should occur.

Answer (score 2):

For a normal(not `final`) java variable, you can assign a value to a variable `n` number of times. No issues in that.

Coming to the output problem, the out put is same because there is nothing happening in between the two outputs

```
  // c value here is 40
  System.out.println("c:"+c); //40
  // No miracles happening here ..again going to print the same value.
  System.out.println("c:"+c);// 40
```

For a change try

```
 c=a-b;
System.out.println("c:"+c);
 c=a+b;
System.out.println("c:"+c);
```

You'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you expect. You first set c to be equal 20-20 (0), and then you discarded that result, setting c to be equal 20+20 (40). There is no error in this code, the subtraction line is simply meaningless.